# How to animate flex box items to no width?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, css-animations

I'm attempting to create a hovering navigation bar where the content can scroll underneath it. However, one thing I can't figure out is how to collapse the content of the nav bar when something happens (this example, one of the nav items are clicked).

Each nav item is flexed so take up only enough space as it needs. However, when setting the flex-grow value from 1 to 0.00001, the actual width of the items does not change.

Is there something I'm missing around forcing this flex box to shrink the width so that it can be animated?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div><Header/><main>This will contain some content that is scrollable and under the nav bar.</main></div>;
  }
}

class Header extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = { collapse: false };
  }
  
  handleNavClick = () => {
   this.setState({ collapse: !this.state.collapse });
  };

  render() {
    return <header>
    <nav>
      <a className={this.state.collapse ? 'collapsed' : null } onClick={this.handleNavClick}>This</a>
      <a className={this.state.collapse ? 'collapsed' : null } onClick={this.handleNavClick}>Is</a>
      <a className={this.state.collapse ? 'collapsed' : null } onClick={this.handleNavClick}>A</a>
      <a className={this.state.collapse ? 'collapsed' : null } onClick={this.handleNavClick}>Navigation</a>
      <a className={this.state.collapse ? 'collapsed' : null } onClick={this.handleNavClick}>Bar</a>
    </nav>
  </header>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
header {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

header > nav {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  padding-right: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.7);
  pointer-events: auto;
}

header > nav > a {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.1em;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1.0);
  padding: 0.5em 0.85em 0.5em 0.85em;
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: flex-grow 1s ease-in-out;
}

header > nav > a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.collapsed {
  flex-grow: 0.00001;
  color: rgba(250, 125, 125, 1.0);
}

main {
  height: 120vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

some notes:

- "default" is not a valid value for `pointer-events`. I think you mean "auto"
- Flex-grow does not control the width of the element itself, but how much of the available extra space on the flex container it will take.
- The actual width is controlled either by flex-basis, or width.
- As you have not set a width for the flex-container, the elements are not really growing at all, so you cannot use the flex-grow to control them.

So you need to simply set a width on your flex-container (in this case, the nav), or try setting and animating flex-basis / widths.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div><Header/><main>This will contain some content that is scrollable and under the nav bar.</main></div>;
  }
}

class Header extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = { collapse: false };
  }
  
  handleNavClick = () => {
   this.setState({ collapse: !this.state.collapse });
  };

  render() {
    return <header>
    <nav>
      <a className={this.state.collapse ? 'collapsed' : null } onClick={this.handleNavClick}>This</a>
      <a className={this.state.collapse ? 'collapsed' : null } onClick={this.handleNavClick}>Is</a>
      <a className={this.state.collapse ? 'collapsed' : null } onClick={this.handleNavClick}>A</a>
      <a className={this.state.collapse ? 'collapsed' : null } onClick={this.handleNavClick}>Navigation</a>
      <a className={this.state.collapse ? 'collapsed' : null } onClick={this.handleNavClick}>Bar</a>
    </nav>
  </header>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
header {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

header > nav {
  width:80%;
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  padding-right: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.7);
  pointer-events: auto;
}

header > nav > a {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.1em;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1.0);
  padding: 0.5em 0.85em 0.5em 0.85em;
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: flex-grow 1s ease-in-out;
}

header > nav > a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: default;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.collapsed {
  flex-grow: 0.00001;
  color: rgba(250, 125, 125, 1.0);
}

main {
  height: 120vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```